# Event is not firing while navigating to external page using pagecontainer

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

Html 1 : first page

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
            $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";
            $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled =true;
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled= false;
        });            
</script>
<script src="js/jquery-mobile.1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).on("pagecreate",function(){
    $(".anchor").click(function(){
       $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "second.html" , { transition:"pop"});
     });       
 });
</script>
```

Html 2: Second Page

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
            $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";
            $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled =true;
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled= false;
        });            
</script>
<script src="js/jquery-mobile.1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).on("pagecreate",function(){

    alert("Instead of alert im going to use ajax ");
 });
```

**Question :**

I tried to change page from first page to second using pagecontainer and it's working fine.
Problem is
I need to load some content in second page using ajax and pagecreate,pageshow nothing is working while changing the page but if i run the second page separately it's working ... 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to solve this problem you need to understand how jQuery Mobile page handling works, and you can't solve this problem.

When jQuery Mobile handles pages only first **HTML** files is fully loaded into the **DOM**, all intermediate files are loaded only partially. When I say partially I mean **HEAD** will be stripped away and only FIRST **data-role="page"** will be loaded.

So if you have 2 pages, for example lets say first one is called **main.html** and second one is called **second.html**, and lats say both of them hava 5 **data-role="page"** div containers.

All pages inside **main.html** will be loaded into the DOM during app initialization, but when you you change page to **second.html** only first **data-role="page"** div container will be loaded into the **DOM**, everything else is going to be discarded.

Read more about it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/multipage-template-vs-multi-html-template-in-jquery-mobile/)** + solutions.

Comment: +1 for giving brief explanation thank u..but sorry to ask this coz I need to resolve this ....Is there any way to clear first page content from DOM and then redirect to second page

Comment: Only way to do so is to turn of AJAX page handling. It can be done through mobileinit event, by using rel="external" in your a tag links or by adding reload : true to pagecontainer( "change", .... function

Comment: it seems like reload: true still has an issue. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7406

Comment: I don't think it will change; jQuery Mobile is a dead framework